# Dropdown menu(ul li kind) not working in ie

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a cross browser compatible drop down menu that is in this site:
[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/overclock351/nqk44oad/)
(check tags with id listdelete in thehtml/css file and javascript is for other purposes)
But my problem is that this version with the ul tags setted as "primary menu" works perfectly on chrome/firefox but it's not gonna work on ie because(i don't know why) the menu is not popping up.
i have tried to change the first #listdelete tags into the leftcont div to a tags and the menus pop up but links are not going to work(i guess that is because the links witch are a tags do not work in the list because the primary list is an a tag itself)
For anithing just ask in comments
HTML:

```
        <div id="wrapperlink">
            <ul>

                <li><a id="temple"href="storia.html"/></a></li>
                <li><a id="gallery"href="gallery.html"/></a></li>
                <li><a id="play"href="video.html"/></a></li>
                <li><a id="info"href="info.html"/></a></li>


            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="leftcont">
            <div class="wrapcont">
                    <div style="text-align:center;font-size:1.3em;"><b>Componenti aereo</b></div>                   

                <ul class="listdelete">
                    <li>
                <span><b>ALI</b></span>
                        <ul class="listdelete">
                        <li class="middle">
                            <b>Disegni</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Componenti</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Lavori</b>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="listdelete">
                    <li>
                <span><b>CARRELLO</b></span>
                        <ul class="listdelete">
                        <li class="middle">
                            <b>Disegni</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Componenti</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Lavori</b>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                        <ul class="listdelete">
                    <li>
                <span class="spanwidth"><b> CRUSCOTTO</b> </span>
                        <ul class="listdelete">
                        <li class="middle">
                            <b>Disegni</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Componenti</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Lavori</b>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="listdelete">
                    <li>
                <span><b>   ELICA</b></span>
                        <ul class="listdelete">
                        <li class="middle">
                            <b>Disegni</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Componenti</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Lavori</b>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                        <ul class="listdelete">
                            <li>
                            <span>  <b>FUSOLIERA</b> </span>
                            <ul class="listdelete">
                            <li class="middle">
                            <a href="#">Disegni</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Componenti</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Lavori</b>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                    <ul class="listdelete">
                            <li>
                            <span><b>LONGHERONE</b> </span>
                            <ul class="listdelete">
                            <li class="middle">
                            <a>Disegni</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <a>Componenti</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <a href="menu laterali/longheroni/lavori/lavoro_longheroni.html">Lavori</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                    <ul class="listdelete">
                            <li>
                            <span>  <b>MOTORE</b> </span>
                            <ul class="listdelete">
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Disegni</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Componenti</b>
                            </li>
                            <li class="middle">
                            <b>Lavori</b>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
        </div>



        <div id="centercontpos">        
            <div id="centercont">
                <div class="wrapcont">
                    <div id="desc">
                    <div style="text-align:center;width:100%;    height:auto;    font-size:1.3em;font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode;"><b></b>    </div><br>
<div style="text-align:center;width:100%;height:auto;font-size:1.1em;     font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode;"></div>
<br>
                        </div>
                        <div id="pusher1">
                        </div>
                        <div id="pic1">
                            <div id="slider">
                            <img id="1"style="border-radius:     18px;width:100%;height:100%;" src="../immagini/slide1.jpg"     border="0"style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
                            <img id="2"style="border-radius:     18px;width:100%;height:100%;" src="../immagini/slide2.jpg"     border="0"style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
                            <img id="3"style="border-radius:     18px;width:100%;height:100%;" src="../immagini/slide3.jpg"     border="0"style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
                            <img id="4"style="border-radius:     18px;width:100%;height:100%;" src="../immagini/slide4.jpg"     border="0"style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
                            <img id="5"style="border-radius:     18px;width:100%;height:100%;" src="../immagini/slide5.jpg"     border="0"style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                   </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
                <div id="rightcont">
                    <div class="wrapcont">
                        <div id="lastarticlepos">
                            <div id="lastarticlediv">
                                <div style="border-bottom:1px solid black;">
                                    <b>ULTIMI ARTICOLI</b>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  

        </div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body{
background-image:url("../immagini/polaroid.jpg");
background-size:cover;
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
min-width:1100px;
min-height:1000px;
}
body,html{
height:100%;width:100%;
min-width:1000px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 900px){
#link{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:20%;
background-color: rgba(255,246,0,0.9);

}
#wrapperlink{
position:relative;
width:90%;
height:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#link ul{
position:absolute;
width:90%;
height:90%;
list-style:none;
margin:auto;
padding:0px;
}
#link li{
float:left;
width:4em;
height:100%;
margin-right:5%;
}
#link a{
float:left;
width:4em;
height:100%;
}
 }
#logo{
position:absolute;  
background-image:url("../immagini/logo.png");   
width:14.563em;
height:100%;
background-size:contain;
background-repeat:no-repeat;    
}
#title{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:15%;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
#link{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:8%;
background-image:url("../immagini/linkbg.png");
background-size:contain;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
#wrapperlink{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#link ul{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
list-style:none;
margin:auto;
padding:0px;
}
#link li{
float:left;
width:4em;
height:100%;
margin-right:5%;
}
#link a{
float:left;
width:4em;
height:90%;
}
#container{
position:relative;
min-width:100%;
height:85%;
background-color: rgba(136,136,136,0.9);
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#footer{
position:relative;
background-image:url("../immagini/footer.png");
width:100%;
height:20%;
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
box-sizing:border-box;
bottom:0;
}
#home{
position:absolute;
background-image:url("../immagini/home1.png");
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
}
#temple{
position:absolute;
background-image:url("../immagini/storia.png");
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
}
#gallery{
position:absolute;
background-image:url("../immagini/gallery.png");
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
}
#info{
position:absolute;
background-image:url("../immagini/info.png");
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
}
#play{
position:absolute;
background-image:url("../immagini/play.png");
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
}
.wrapcont{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#leftcont{
position:absolute;
border:black solid 2px;
height:100%;
width:20%;
left:0;
box-sizing:border-box;

}
#centercont{
position:absolute;
border:black solid 2px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:auto;
background-color: rgba(200,80,30,0.9);
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#rightcont{
position:absolute;
border:black solid 2px;
height:100%;
width:20%;
right:0;
top:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#centercontpos{
position:relative;
width:60%;
height:100%;
margin:auto;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#engsite{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;    
background-image:url("../immagini/eng.png");
width:3em;
height:1.9215em;    
background-size:contain;    
border:2px solid grey;
}
#itasite{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;    
background-image:url("../immagini/itaflag.png");
width:3em;
height:1.9215em;
background-size:contain;    
border:2px solid grey;
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------lateral bar opening--------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------lateral bar opening--------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------lateral bar opening--------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------lateral bar opening--------------------------------*/
.listdelete{
position:relative;
list-style:none;
display:inline;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:auto;
font-size:1em;
}
.listdelete>li{
text-align:center;
}
.spanwidth{
width:30px;
text-align:center;
}
.listdelete>li:hover span{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
background-color:red;
}
.listdelete>li>.listdelete>li{
display:none;
background-color:white;
width:auto;
margin:0;
height:auto;
}
.listdelete:hover li>.listdelete>li{
display:block;
background-color:white;
margin:0;
width:auto;
font-size:0.8em;
text-align:center;
}
.primo{
border-top-left-radius: 25px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
border-bottom:1px grey solid;
}
.ultimo{
border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
.middle{
border-bottom:1px grey solid;
}
/*------------------------------------------------------------lateral bar close--------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------lateral bar close--------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------lateral bar close--------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------lateral bar close--------------------------------*/
#desc{
border:black solid 2px;
border-radius: 25px;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:auto%;
background-image:url("../immagini/descbg.png");
background-size:cover;
}
#pusher1{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:5em;
}
#pic1{
border:black solid 2px;
border-radius: 18px;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width:80%;
height:40%;
background-color:red;
}
.spancenter{
position:relative;
width:auto;
margin:auto;
}
#slider{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0px;
}
#lastarticlepos{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:80%;
border:black solid 2px;
border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: what ie version? Forgetting about poorest UX ever it actually works for me on ie11

Comment: the ie version is ie10.0.9

Comment: i think i have solved the problem with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234254/how-to-get-css-hover-event-to-trigger-in-ie-when-mouse-is-over-text-of-input-ele

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that IE doesn't understand the "hover" attribute with tag "li". It only applies to tag "a". Try to solve your problem by inserting "if ie" blocks with links instead of list elements. Here's an example (a little different task but still can help): http:// jsfiddle. net/xan9gtde/

Pay attention that the commented CSS-block must be in different CSS-file for IE only.

Comment: <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <a href="">Section 2
        <table><tr><td>
        <![endif]--> i gotta put even this stuff in a different html file? (i can't found info on this if statement in html)

Comment: I cannot use links anyway because a link inside a link (even on ie) do not work and i want to put links in the secondary options, is there an alternative to a tags?

Comment: No, this stuff should be in your html.


If you can't use links, then write the following:

<style>
/* common css */
</style>
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<style>
/* ie6 css */
</style>
<![endif]-->

Comment: i don't think that making a web browser selection is a good think because there are a lot of browsers online